# How to either override text drawing in OutlinedTextField or draw label and border in BaseTextField?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to rewrite existing custom date of birth view with Compose, that looks like:
[image]
Not shown on the image but when not fully filled there should be hint like DD / MM / YYYY, and these hint chars should be replaced with entered digits one by one.
However width of a text should not change when different digits are entered, i.e. it must either use monospace font (how it is implemented currently, but discouraged by designers) or to use non-monospace font but calculate maximum char box and draw text char per char each in same sized box.

The latter approach is easy to do with BaseTextField, but then no fancy label is available.
How can it be done without drawing border and label by hands? Or how the border and label can be drawn in scope of BaseTextField's decorationBox?

**The question is not about transforming 07281991 to 07/28/1991, but about drawing all digits with the same width in scope of OutlinedTextField without using monospace font.**